# How to use xmlserialize, xmlagg, xmltext in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How to convert this DB2 query to PostgreSQL

```
substring(xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(concat('::',trim(description)))) as varchar(1024)), 3) as disc_code
```

Comment: What does this query do? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

To convert this DB2 query to PostgreSQL, you can use the `string_agg()` function, which is similar to the `xmlagg()` function in DB2. The `string_agg()` function concatenates a set of strings into a single string, with a separator character between each string.